# C++ libcurl headers - not recognised by server

Tags: c++, curl, header, lib

I'm working in C++ with libcurl writing a program to interact with some APIs and I'm stuck when it comes to adding authentication info in the headers. I am new to libcurl and APIs with a basic knowledge of C++. Authentication requires an API key and a nonce hashed with HMAC_SHA256, each of which is then placed in the headers. A very simple JSON message is then sent. I've tried searching through this site but most examples seem to be in javascript or command line, and I don't see any relevant answers in them.

When I send my POST message to the server, I get a response 402 - Invalid ApiKey. My API key is 100% correct so I suspect it's something to do with the formatting or the way I've included it in the header. The site is BlinkTrade and their documentation is [here](https://blinktrade.com/docs/?shell#trade-api), which gives some info about the header requirements.

Code snippet below:

```
char* message="{\"MsgType\": \"U2\",\"BalanceReqID\": 1}";
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.blinktrade.com/tapi/v1/message");
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, fwrite);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, pFile2);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1L);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, message);

struct curl_slist *header = NULL;
header = curl_slist_append(header, "APIKey:0000000000000000000000000000000000000000");    
header = curl_slist_append(header, "Nonce:1");
header = curl_slist_append(header, "Signature:1");
header = curl_slist_append(header, "Content-Type:application/json");
transfer = curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, header);
cout << transfer << endl;

transfer = curl_easy_perform(curl);
cout << transfer << endl;
```

And I get the return code 0 for curl_easy_setopt and curl_easy_perform. I've swapped the actual characters from the API key for a load of 0's, but otherwise everything is the same in terms of formatting etc. I've not actually used a hashed signature, I'll do that after I can sort out this error. I've tried adding a space after the colon and enclosing string and/or value in double quotes but I get the same response. What am I doing wrong that means my headers aren't actually recognised by the server?

Comment: Your Signature does not look like `HMAC-SHA256` of something. Is it also just a sample or real value?

Comment: @ArtemyVysotsky I'm submitting a value of 1 hoping to get a server response for an invalid signature, rather than invalid API (just trying to control all the other variables until I can fix this issue). If you happen to know how this should be added that will help when I come to it, is it just added as a string?

Comment: you can see it by yourself https://www.freeformatter.com/hmac-generator.html - put your nonce as value and key as secret and select SHA256

Answer (score 0):

Solved: the Blinktrade server returns "Invalid APIKey" not when your API key is incorrect, but when the signature is incorrect. A rather annoying mislabelling.